# CSS GRID auto-fit не изменяет ширину элементов

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Доброго времени суток!

Решил наверстать шаблон с помощью CSS GRID и столкнулся с необъяснимой(для меня) реакцией на изменение размера рабочей области браузера. вместо того чтобы плавно изменять ширину входящих в главных блок элементов он их перекидывает на новую строку:

```css
.content-div 
{
  background: black;
}

.center-div {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

.two-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 575px));
  /* либо minmax(300px, 1fr); тоже не работает.*/
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.children {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-div">
  <div class="center-div two-div">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Если у блока явно указано minmax(300px, 575px)]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы достичь результата где:
 При размере рабочей области > 1170px center-div имел размер не более 1170px но и внутренние элементы были не равны размерам min-width. А при изменении размера рабочей области в меньшую сторону элементы находящиеся в center-div уменьшались до размеров которые равняются min-width после чего переходили на новую строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> либо minmax(300px, 1fr); тоже не работает.

1fr работает корректно с данной функцией, растягивая каждый из элементов суммарно до ширины в 1170px, которая задана в стилях. Может Вы что-то напутали?

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/aboZjGO)

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.center-div {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

.two-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  /* либо minmax(300px, 1fr); тоже не работает. */
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.children {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-div">
  <div class="center-div two-div">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, все верно =) Ваш код работает так как мне и нужно ))) Дело в том что родительский блок всех блоков в примере имел     display: flex;  XD

Answer (score 0):

Зачем усложнять?
У вас в `.center-div` строго прописаны ограничения, просто сделайте родителю `.children` - `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)`, больше или меньше ограничения они не будут.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.center-div {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  min-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

.two-div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.children {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-div">
  <div class="center-div two-div">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```